# publishing iPhone apps without owning a website and tax details?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I am an iPhone developer from India and want to publish my iPhone apps to the app store using Apple's "Individual Developer" program.

But the catch is I don't own a website. Can I publish an iPhone app without specifying a support website at iTunes connect? Is it mandatory to specify a website there?

I am a non US resident. What should I do while filing tax details? Should I leave it blank? What would be the effect of leaving it blank?

Answer (score 2):

You can't leave these fields empty, for the website, you can host a web page describing your app in any free hosting provider, and use the url!

For the tax details, you have to specify your bank account info! and depending on that, itunes connect can tell you if it needs more tax details or not!